# openjdk 8 running in FIPS mode produces java.security.InvalidKeyException: Could not create key

Tags: java, fips

I am trying to configure Java to run in FIPS mode. I am running openjdk 1.8.0 and NSS 3.79.0 on an AmazonLinux2 AWS instance. As per whatever documentation I could find, I configured the java.security file (security providers and keystore.type only):

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 /opt/fipsconfig/pkcs11.cfg
security.provider.2=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider SunPKCS11-NSSFIPS
```

and

```
keystore.type=PKCS11
```

Next, I configured the /opt/fipsconfig/pkcs11.cfg token to be:

```
[root@ip-10-4-93-132 hmac-test]# cat /opt/fipsconfig/pkcs11.cfg
name = NSSFIPS
nssLibraryDirectory = /usr/lib64
nssSecmodDirectory = /etc/pki/nssdb
nssModule = fips
nssDbMode = readOnly
```

I then verified that /etc/pki/nssdb is FIPS enabled:

```
modutil -chkfips true -dbdir /etc/pki/nssdb
FIPS mode enabled.
```

And the token looks good:

```
modutil -dbdir /etc/pki/nssdb -list

Listing of PKCS #11 Modules
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1. NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module
       uri: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;library-description=NSS%20Internal%20Crypto%20Services;library-version=3.79
     slots: 1 slot attached
    status: loaded

     slot: NSS FIPS 140-2 User Private Key Services
    token: NSS FIPS 140-2 Certificate DB
      uri: pkcs11:token=NSS%20FIPS%20140-2%20Certificate%20DB;manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;serial=0000000000000000;model=NSS%203
```

---

Using this demo:

```
[root@ip-10-4-93-132 hmac-test]# cat hmac.java
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.KeyStore;

    public class hmac {
    public static String encode(String algorithm, String key, String data) throws Exception {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
        if (ks == null) System.out.println("ks is null");
        else {
            ks.load(null, null);
            System.out.println("keystore PKCS11 type = " + ks.getDefaultType());
            System.out.println("keystore PKCS11 provider = " + ks.getProvider());
            System.out.println("keystore PKCS11 size = " + ks.size());
        }

        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        //System.out.println("HMAC Provider: " + sha256_HMAC.getProvider());
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), algorithm);
        sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

        byte[] bytes = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aByte : bytes) {
            result.append(String.format("%02x", aByte));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Usage.\nUsage: java hmac <algorithm> <key> <data>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        System.out.println(encode(args[0], args[1], args[2]));
    }
}
```

produces this error when run with the following options:

```
java hmac HmacSHA256 "key" "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
keystore PKCS11 type = PKCS11
keystore PKCS11 provider = SunPKCS11-NSSFIPS version 1.8
keystore PKCS11 size = 2
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Could not create key
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11SecretKeyFactory.createKey(P11SecretKeyFactory.java:274)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11SecretKeyFactory.convertKey(P11SecretKeyFactory.java:179)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11SecretKeyFactory.convertKey(P11SecretKeyFactory.java:111)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Mac.engineInit(P11Mac.java:204)
    at javax.crypto.Mac.chooseProvider(Mac.java:350)
    at javax.crypto.Mac.init(Mac.java:415)
    at hmac.encode(hmac.java:19)
    at hmac.main(hmac.java:34)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_CreateObject(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11SecretKeyFactory.createKey(P11SecretKeyFactory.java:269)
    ... 7 more
```

If I run the demo in full java debug mode, with:

```
java -Djava.security.debug=all hmac HmacSHA256 key "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"  > OUT 2>&1
```

The output looks reasonable, except for the exception produced at the very end.

I've looked all over the internet for a hint on what is going wrong, but I just can't seem to find anything. I took a look at the P11SecretKeyFactory.java code, and I believe the initial exception thrown is of type PKCS11Exception (where it then prints the "Could not create key" and then throws the new InvalidKeyException).

In the createKey() function, I see 3 attributes are being set:

```
        attributes[0] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_CLASS, CKO_SECRET_KEY);
        attributes[1] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_KEY_TYPE, keyType);
        attributes[2] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_VALUE, encoded);
```

I am wondering if one of these attributes (probably the last 2) could be producing the CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID error?

Has anyone run across this and if so would you be able to provide a clue as to what is wrong?

Thank you.